# Android UI Slows Down on View setRotation

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, user-interface, rotation

I have around 20 RelativeLayouts inside a FrameLayout that i use for Stack like this:

[image: cardsbehindeachother]
The rotation of the views is set in the constructor with the following lines:

```
float minX = -4.3f;
float maxX = 4.3f;

Random rand = new Random();
float finalX = rand.nextFloat() * (maxX - minX) + minX;
setRotation(finalX);
```

There is a on Touch on the Views where you can move the "Sheets" around and throw it away. 
Now i have the problem, that the UI goes very slow, if i add some more sheets. 
On 3-5 Sheets/Views there is no problem, on 20-30 it goes really slow. As soon as i remove the rotation everything works fine. 
If i do a lower Rotation, it gets better, but it is still slow.

Is there any way to use the rotation without slowing down the ui?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it - after some research i stumbled upon this article:

http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/optimizing-view.html

After adding

```
setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
```

everything is working smooth.